# Exit from a sourced script that exports variables

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that exports some variables:

**my_script.sh**

```
export var="Hello"
```

If I execute this script from the terminal when script finishes to persist variables I can execute it with:

```
source my_script.sh
```

or

```
. my_script.sh
```

Now I want to add logic somewhere in my script to exit from it in the middle. If I just use `exit 0` inside of my **my_script.sh** this will close current terminal with the way of running described above. I want to exit from the script inside of a nested function, so `return` keyword won't do.

**edit**:
example of the flow:

```
test() {
 export a='Make this variable to be exported'
 test2
 echo 'make this command gone'
}

test2() {
 return
}

test
```

Is there any way to do both: exit from the middle of the script and export vars from it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add return statement checks every time you nest. Ie.

```sh
test() {
 export a='Make this variable to be exported'
 test2 || return 1
 echo 'make this command gone'
}

test2() {
 return 1
}

test
```

Comment: Please check my comment to @lnian